# Iconv::IllegalSequence in filename saved by wget (Ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: ruby, utf-8, find, wget, iconv

I'm saving files to an ext2 partition with wget using normal flags. Retrieving their names sometimes fails:

```
s = `find "#{@dir}" -type f -printf "%T@\t::::\t%s\t::::\t%p\n" |sort`
s.each_line {|l|
   file_name = l.chomp.split("\t::::\t")[2] #=> 
   # ...66:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
}
```

Tests:

```
l.encoding #=> UTF-8
l.valid_encoding #=> false
l.inspect #=> "...St. Paul\xE2%80%99s Cathedral..."
Iconv.conv('utf-8', 'utf-8', l) #=> 
# ...77:in `conv': "\xE2%80%99s Cathedr"... (Iconv::IllegalSequence)
```

How can I get the file name and delete the file?

Forgot to mention, in bash the file looks like:

```
index.php?attTag=St. Paul?%80%99s Cathedral
```

Pasting this string back into ls returns no such file or directory.

Comment: Cause is is probably an intentional bug in wget -- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=411290.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `CGI.unescape` before running the conversion...

```
a = "...St. Paul\xE2%80%99s Cathedral..."
puts a

require 'cgi'
b = CGI.unescape a
puts b

require 'iconv'
c = Iconv.conv('UTF-8//TRANSLIT', 'UTF-8', b) # may not even be necessary
puts c
```

Which outputs on my ruby-1.9.2-p180:

```
...St. Paul?%80%99s Cathedral...
...St. Paul’s Cathedral...
...St. Paul’s Cathedral...
```

Comment: I had to do "a.force_encoding('us-ascii')" first and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I was too hasty. This isn't how the filename looks in bash. I've added this to my question.